# Is there a way to manage what POJO class properties get stored in Firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Android app I have a POI class with the following properties and constructors:

```
/**
 * A POJO class for a POI (Point Of Interest)
 */
@Parcel
public class POI {
    String id;
    String name;
    int release;
    Double latitude;
    Double longitude;
    String description;
    String img_url;
    String collection;
    int collectionPosition;
    String stampText;
    boolean stampChecked; // Has the POI been checked to be stamped?
    Stamp stamp;

public POI(){}

public POI(String id){
    this.id = id;}

public POI(String id,
           String name,
           int release,
           Double latitude,
           Double longitude,
           String description,
           String img_url,
           String collection,
           int collectionPosition,
           String stampText) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.release = release;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.description = description;
    this.img_url = img_url;
    this.collection = collection;
    this.collectionPosition = collectionPosition;
    this.stampText = stampText;
    this.stampChecked = false;
}
```

When I store POI objects in Firestore I get two problems happening.

1. Firestore creates a stamp property, apparently because I have a stamp property in my POI class. My POI model has a Stamp property because I need it for my code purposes only. I don't need it stored in the database.  Is there a way, like an annotation that I can use to tell Firestore what fields it can ignore?
2. Firestore creates a property called 'stamped', even though I do NOT have any such property in my POI class.  The only reason I can guess this is happening is because I have the following method in my class:

   ```
   public boolean isStamped(){
        return (stamp instanceof Stamp);
   }
   ```

Is there a way to tell Firebase to ignore certain properties or to force Firebase to use a specific constructor, *without having to get rid of or renaming my getters and setters*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Exclude) annotation on a field or method to prevent it from being serialized.

In the following class, the "bar" property will not appear when serialized, as the getter is annotated with @Exclude.

```
public class Foo {

    private String thing;
    private String bar;

    public Foo() {
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getThing() {
        return thing;
    }

    public void setThing(String thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }
}
```

Comment: It only works on the getter method, right? When I try it on the field directly, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Unlike in Firebase Realtime database, where non-existing values are not displayed at all, in Cloud Firestore if you add a field which is `null` the result will be `yourField: null`. If you want to make sure that you'll never have `null` values when it comes to objects or empty strings `""` when it comes to strings, when writing a document to Firestore, you can use a `Map` and populate it with only the fields that you want.

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
if (stampChecked != null) {
    map.put("stampChecked", true);
}
//Same for the other properties.

FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
rootRef.collection("yourCollection").document("yourDocument").set(map);
```

If you already have such values in your database, you can use these lines of code to remove them:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("yourField", FieldValue.delete());
yourRef.update(map);
```